# Total test execution time using karma runner

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, karma-runner, browserstack

We've currently switched to running unit tests remotely on [browserstack](http://browserstack.com) in multiple browsers on multiple operating systems with the help of [`karma-browserstack-launcher`](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-browserstack-launcher) plugin.

Currently the output of the test run looks like this:

```
$ grunt unit:remote
Running "unit:remote" task

Running "karma:remote" (karma) task
INFO [karma]: Karma v0.12.23 server started at http://localhost:9876/
INFO [launcher]: Starting browser firefox 21.0 (OS X Mountain Lion) on BrowserStack
INFO [launcher]: Starting browser iPhone 5 (ios 6.0) on BrowserStack
INFO [launcher]: Starting browser android (android 4.1) on BrowserStack
INFO [launcher]: Starting browser ie 8.0 (Windows 7) on BrowserStack
INFO [launcher]: Starting browser ie 9.0 (Windows 7) on BrowserStack
INFO [launcher]: Starting browser chrome latest (OS X Mavericks) on BrowserStack
INFO [launcher]: Starting browser PhantomJS

PhantomJS 1.9.7 (Mac OS X): Executed 70 of 70 SUCCESS (0.063 secs / 0.275 secs)
Chrome 37.0.2062 (Mac OS X 10.9.0): Executed 70 of 70 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0.452 secs)
Mobile Safari 6.0.0 (iOS 6.1.4): Executed 70 of 70 SUCCESS (1.161 secs / 0.839 secs)
Firefox 21.0.0 (Mac OS X 10.8): Executed 70 of 70 SUCCESS (1.175 secs / 0.496 secs)
...
```

There is the execution time being reported *for every browser*.

Is there a way to see the **total execution time** on the console?

---

FYI, here is the [karma config](https://gist.github.com/alecxe/3769707d406add9d8f8b) we are using.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've forked the *karma plugin* and added an option **extraLog** in the `karma browserStack config` to get more information after all your browsers are finished, including the total execution and net time of all your browsers.

I'm mainly using the `browser_complete event` of the `emitter` that give me the `total` and the `net` time of the browser.

```
emitter.on('browser_complete', function (data) {
  result.browsers.push({ name: data.name, time: data.lastResult.totalTime });
  result.time.net += data.lastResult.netTime;
  result.time.total += data.lastResult.totalTime; //this is what we want
});
```

Using three browsers here an example output (sorry I'm not a designer yet) :

[image: screen]

This allows you to get a more accurate result in comparison with *time-grunt*.

You can review the code [here](https://github.com/Apercu/karma-browserstack-launcher/tree/feature-extra-logs) on the *feature-extra-logs* branch.

I don't really know how do you want (and the best practice) to deploy this to you, because I don't think it is interesting enough to be merged to the upstream, but I might be wrong.

Comment: This is really nice of you to implement the feature! I've tried that  - this is exactly what I was asking about. I think this might be a useful feature to have in `karma-browserstack-launcher`. Many thanks!

Comment: You're welcome :) Hum then I should see if I can open a PR on the repo, but I'm scared to be denied, mostly because of my formatting that might not please to everyone. But I'll keep you in touch !

Comment: Thank you very much again for the effort you made. I think it would be a good idea to start an issue on karma-browserstack-launcher's github page and see what maintainers think about the feature. I think I'm not the only one who is missing this sort of functionality. Do you want me to create the issue, or you were going to send them a PR with changes? Thanks.

Comment: I think I'm gonna review what I can improve and submit a PR which asks about the formatting, the parameter name and the use of chalk or not. Probably today or tomorrow. Glad to have helped ! :)

Comment: @alecxe [here](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-browserstack-launcher/pull/14) is the PR for reference

Comment: Thank you for letting me know. Would be glad to see it merged.

Answer (score 3):

Not really karma-specific, but you could use https://github.com/sindresorhus/time-grunt to see how long the entire unit:remote task takes.

Just copying from its readme.md, you can install it using

```
npm install --save-dev time-grunt
```

And then edit your gruntfile as

```
// Gruntfile.js
module.exports = function (grunt) {
  // require it at the top and pass in the grunt instance
  require('time-grunt')(grunt);

  grunt.initConfig();
}
```

Then when you run grunt tasks(s) you should get output like:

[image: time-grunt example]

Comment: Strictly speaking, this is a workaround, but is really good to know about. Thank you very much for bringing this up.